# How to downgrade from SQL2005 Enterprise to SQL2005 Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to downgrade from SQL2005 Enterprise to SQL2005 Standard in Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy path to downgrade. You will need to:

- Take a backup of all your databases
- Uninstall SQL 2005 EE
- Reboot the server
- Re-install SQL 2005 standard, ideally in the same location as the previous version.
- Restore your databases to this new server.

You may be able to make the process quicker by copying your existing databases to another location, doing the re-install and then copying the databases back, overwriting the existing DB's, including the system DBs. However, make sure you have a good backup off all DB's as well in case this does not work as you want.

As Brent said, your also going to want to check that any of your DB's are not using the features of the EE edition.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the only possible solution is to backup all your databases, uninstall SQL Server 2005 Enterprise, install the Standard version and restore the databases.

Don't forget to script any user objects of your master database and other system databases (job definitions etc.)

Comment: You might also want to mention that they can check to see if their databases are using any EE-only features.

Comment: Yes, Brent's absoluteley right. I would test it on a staging machine, before doing this on a production/important server.

Comment: Wht's the command to script out usr obj & system in master db? I'm poor in script.

Comment: Here is a link: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1531  --  Be careful, make a backup of all databases before you begin...